# slice/select netCDF between a range of values of the chosen dimension - Python

Tags: python

I am new to python and to netCDF file manipulation.

I am trying to slice an array by its Depth using the Depth data from two .nc files.

The file I want to slice is `temp`, while the other two files refer to the Mixed Layer Depth in the ocean respectively in winter `mld_winter`, and in summer `mld_summer` (similar in structure and different only in Depth values).

````
>>> temp
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (XC: 2160, YC: 588, Z: 52, time: 84)
Coordinates: (12/15)
    iter       (time) int64 ...
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2013-01-30T20:40:00 ... 2019-12-31T14:20:00
  * XC         (XC) float32 0.08333 0.25 0.4167 0.5833 ... 359.6 359.8 359.9
  * YC         (YC) float32 -77.98 -77.95 -77.91 -77.88 ... -30.02 -29.87 -29.72
  * Z          (Z) float32 -2.1 -6.7 -12.15 -18.55 ... -5e+03 -5.4e+03 -5.8e+03
    rA         (YC, XC) float32 ...
    ...         ...
    maskC      (Z, YC, XC) bool ...
    maskCtrlC  (Z, YC, XC) bool ...
    rhoRef     (Z) float32 ...
    rLowC      (YC, XC) float32 ...
    maskInC    (YC, XC) bool ...
    rSurfC     (YC, XC) float32 ...
Data variables:
    TEMPERATURE     (time, Z, YC, XC) float32 ...



>>> ```mld_winter```
<xarray.DataArray 'Depth' (time: 1, YC: 588, XC: 2160)>
array([[[ -0.      ,  -0.      ,  -0.      , ...,  -0.      ,
          -0.      ,  -0.      ],
        [ -0.      ,  -0.      ,  -0.      , ...,  -0.      ,
          -0.      ,  -0.      ],
        [ -0.      ,  -0.      ,  -0.      , ...,  -0.      ,
          -0.      ,  -0.      ],
        ...,
        [-92.74558 , -91.05976 , -89.990906, ..., -91.42767 ,
         -92.38585 , -92.182274],
        [-90.842384, -90.53973 , -89.26402 , ..., -90.02215 ,
         -89.696655, -88.83551 ],
        [-89.26157 , -89.02418 , -86.94184 , ..., -87.80376 ,
         -87.4023  , -86.835205]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-07-31T22:40:00
  * XC       (XC) float32 0.08333 0.25 0.4167 0.5833 ... 359.4 359.6 359.8 359.9
  * YC       (YC) float32 -77.98 -77.95 -77.91 -77.88 ... -30.02 -29.87 -29.72
````

I am looking for the temperature data within the summer (top) and the winter (bottom) layers, for which:

**mld_winter < temp.Z < mld_summer**

I tried to slice `temp` using `numpy`, as follow:

```
temp_mld = np.squeeze(temp.TEMPERATURE.sel(Z > mld_winter & Z < mld_summer))
NameError: name 'Z' is not defined
```

If I try to slice `temp` by using 1 operator only I obtain:

```
temp_mld = np.squeeze(temp.TEMPERATURE.sel(Z > mld_winter))
NameError: name 'Z' is not defined
```

or

```
temp_mld = np.squeeze(temp.TEMPERATURE.sel(Z = mld_winter))
KeyError: "not all values found in index 'Z'"
```

or

```
temp_mld = np.squeeze(temp.TEMPERATURE.sel(Z > -60)) #-60 is an example
NameError: name 'Z' is not defined
```

**EDITED:**
However, slicing for example by `Z = slice(-6, -40)` it works.
So then, I tried to make a range of values by making a slice with mld data, returning an error still:

```
winter_mld_bound = slice(mld_summer, mld_winter)
temp_mld = np.squeeze(temp.TEMPERATURE.sel(Z = mld_winter_bound))

ValueError: cannot use non-scalar arrays in a slice for xarray indexing: [[[  1.         1.         1.       ...   1.         1.         1.      ]
      [  1.         1.         1.       ...   1.         1.         1.      ]
      [  1.         1.         1.       ...   1.         1.         1.      ]
      ...
      [-91.74558  -90.05976  -88.990906 ... -90.42767  -91.38585  -91.182274]
      [-89.842384 -89.53973  -88.26402  ... -89.02215  -88.696655 -87.83551 ]
      [-88.26157  -88.02418  -85.94184  ... -86.80376  -86.4023   -85.835205]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find the netCDF file you were using (B-SOSE), so the code I've written should work.

These are the packages I use for the code to work

```
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
import xarray as xr
import pooch
```

I use a package called `pooch` to download the data. Check it out, it's quite neat for smaller files. A key part of what I do, is using the `dask` part of `xarray`. It allows one to use lazy loading for netCDF files, meaning that data aren't loaded until they absolutely have to be.
This means you can work with files that are actually quite a bit larger than your memory (this doesn't always work).

```
def download(url):
    """pooch is a package to download data - returns the local file path"""
    fname = pooch.retrieve(
        url, None, 
        fname=url.split('/')[-1],
        path='some_data_repository/bsose/iter133/', 
        downloader=pooch.HTTPDownloader(progressbar=True))
    
    return fname

# download the data and return the local fname
mld_fname = download('http://sose.ucsd.edu/SO6/ITER133/bsose_i133_2013to2018_30day_MLD.nc')
# I use xr.open_mfdataset since it automatically uses dask and does lazy computing
# this means that it doesnt load the data until the last possible moment
mld = xr.open_mfdataset(mld_fname).BLGMLD

tmp_fname = download("http://sose.ucsd.edu/SO6/ITER133/bsose_i133_2013to2018_monthly_Theta.nc")
temp = xr.open_mfdataset(tmp_fname, chunks=dict(time=12, Z=5)).THETA

# I make depth positive since MLD is positive and we want to compare these
depth = -temp.Z
```

The next step is to find the entrainment layer (at least that's how I understand it). I've just done this based on the climatology since it's easier. Of course you can do this for interannual data, but it takes a bit of trickery with the dates.

```
# groupby is amazing, I use it a lot - read the documentation
mld_season_clim = mld.groupby('time.season').mean('time')
mld_smr_clim = mld_season_clim.sel(season='DJF')
mld_wnt_clim = mld_season_clim.sel(season='JJA')

# The entrainment layer is the water mass between the winter and summer climatology
# this has to be compared against depth - note that we changed the sign of 
# depth to be compatible with MLD earlier on. The output is a boolean mask (True|False)
entrainment_layer = (depth > mld_smr_clim) & (depth < mld_wnt_clim)
```

And finally, we can use the `bool` mask to select data for the entrainment layer. The `drop=True` part of the function call simply removes a row/col if there is no data (for memory savings). This means that you'll lose the very deep depths in the temperature. The output here will still be "lazy" so to actually load this data, one needs to used `.load() / .compute()`

```
entrainment_temp = temp.where(entrainment_layer, drop=True)

with ProgressBar():
    entrainment_temp = entrainment_temp.compute()
```

And that should do the trick!

Lastly, I've written a quick function to plot the data with `cartopy`. Based on the output here, I think I've done the right thing.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from cartopy import crs, feature


def plot_bsose(da, **kwargs):
    """for quick plotting SPstereo maps"""
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(
        figsize=[6, 5], dpi=120, 
        subplot_kw=dict(projection=crs.SouthPolarStereo(true_scale_latitude=55)))
    
    props = dict(robust=True, cbar_kwargs=dict(pad=0.01), transform=crs.PlateCarree())
    props.update(kwargs)
    
    img = da.plot(ax=ax, **props)
    
    ax.coastlines(lw=0.5, zorder=11)
    ax.add_feature(feature.LAND, fc='w', zorder=10)
    ax.spines['geo'].set_zorder(12)
    ax.spines['geo'].set_lw(0.5)
    
    return img


img = plot_bsose(entrainment_layer.sum('Z'), vmax=15, vmin=2)
img.axes.set_title('Depth layers between winter/summer MLDs')
img.colorbar.set_label('Number of depth layers')
```

[image]